# CQ5 ExtJs checkbox state not maintained

Tags: extjs, aem

I have written a custom multifield which has some textfield and a checkbox. The issue is that when I select the checkbox and close the dialog after clicking on the OK and reopen the dialog the checkbox loses its state and I have to select it again. Here is the code:

```
var MMCCamCar = {};

MMCCamCar.SubdomainCarouselWidget = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.Hidden
     */
    hiddenField : null,

    headline:null,
    subheadline:null,
    slideImage:null,
    slideAltText:null,
    slideURL:null,
    urlText:null,
    openInNewWindow: null,
    emptyField:null,


    constructor : function(config) {
        config = config || {};
        var defaults = {
            "border" : true
        };
        config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
        MMCCamCar.SubdomainCarouselWidget.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    // overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
    initComponent : function() {
        MMCCamCar.SubdomainCarouselWidget.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

        this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
            name : this.name
        });
        this.add(this.hiddenField);


        this.headline = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel : "Headline",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            maxLength : "50",
            width : 400,
            allowBlank : true,
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.headline);

        this.subheadline = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel : "Sub headline",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            maxLength : "50",
            width : 400,
            allowBlank : true,
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.subheadline);

        this.slideImage = new CQ.form.PathField({
            fieldLabel : "Banner Image",
            fieldDescription : "Specify image path of Dim: 965 x 347",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            rootPath : "/content/dam/mercer/965x347",
            editable : false,
            width : 400,
            allowBlank : true,
            listeners : {
                dialogselect : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                },
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.slideImage);

        this.slideAltText = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel : "Image Alt Text",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:92px;',
            maxLength : "40",
            width : 400,
            allowBlank : true,
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.slideAltText);

        this.slideURL = new CQ.form.PathField({
            fieldLabel : "Complete URL for the Slide",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            rootPath : "/content/mercer",
            editable : true,
            width : 400,
            allowBlank : true,
            listeners : {
                dialogselect : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                },
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.slideURL);



        this.urlText = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel : "Link URL text",
            labelStyle : 'display:block;width:85px;',
            maxLength : "50",
            width : 400,
            allowBlank : true,
            listeners : {
                change : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.updateHidden
                }
            }
        });
        this.add(this.urlText);


        this.openInNewWindow =  new CQ.form.Selection({
            type:"checkbox",
            fieldLabel: "Check to open in New window",
             options:displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainCarousel(),
            listeners: {
                selectionchanged: {
                    scope:this,
                    fn: this.updateHidden
                }
            },
            optionsProvider: this.optionsProvider
        });
        this.add(this.openInNewWindow);


        /**
         * Added a dummy Empty field to avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception in the resultant array
         * Without this hidden field, the empty values will be not be added to the multifield list
         */
        this.emptyField = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel: "Empty Field",
            width:200,
            maxLength: "30",
            defaultValue: "empty",
            hidden:true,
            value:"empty",
        });
        this.add(this.emptyField);

    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
    setValue : function(value) {

        var parts = value.split(/<#-@>/);
        console.log("SubdomainCarouselMultiLinksWidget#parts", parts);
        this.headline.setValue(parts[0]);
        this.subheadline.setValue(parts[1]);
        this.slideImage.setValue(parts[2]);
        this.slideAltText.setValue(parts[3]);
        this.slideURL.setValue(parts[4]);
        this.urlText.setValue(parts[5]);
        this.openInNewWindow.setValue(parts[6]);
        this.emptyField.setValue(parts[7]);


        this.hiddenField.setRawValue(value);

    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
    getValue : function() {
        return this.getRawValue();
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getRawValue
    getRawValue : function() {
        return this.headline.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.subheadline.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.slideImage.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.slideAltText.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.slideURL.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.urlText.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.slideURL.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.openInNewWindow.getValue() + "<#-@>"
                + this.emptyField.getValue()
    },

    // private
    updateHidden : function() {
        this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
    }

});

function displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainCarousel()
{
    return [{
        "text":"check to open link in new tab",
        "value":"true"

    }]
}

// register xtype
MMCCamCar.SubdomainCarouselWidget.XTYPE = "subdomainCarousel";
CQ.Ext.reg(MMCCamCar.SubdomainCarouselWidget.XTYPE, MMCCamCar.SubdomainCarouselWidget);
```

Comment: If the value gets saved to the JCR, it sounds like the issue is with resetting the value on init of your dialog, rather than a problem with setting the value on save. I'd suggest liberally placing `console.log` statements throughout your code & also checking your dev tools for errors in the JS. If this doesn't point to the problem, reduce the code to the minimum required to reproduce it — e.g. possibly just the checkbox in the custom multifield. At this stage, you'll have a much better idea of what could be causing the problem. As is, your question is quite high-level.

Comment: For my current project (using 5.5), I tried and failed to make an multifield with a checkbox in it -- I experienced a similar problem with roundtripping the selection to the CRX and back to the UI.  What worked for me: a multifield with a selection dropdown (with two choices).

Comment: Hi anotherdave. Thanks for your inputs.Just wanted to know where does the console.log prints statements.In any log file etc ?

Comment: @user972418 The `console.log` statement will print to the JavaScript console in the browser, e.g. Dev tool panel in Chrome or the Firebug in FF. You could use `alert` if you prefer, but they get quite annoying :) In Firebug/Chrome you should also be able to set breakpoints &:inspect values at certain points.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `stateful` flag for handling this case:

```
    this.openInNewWindow =  new CQ.form.Selection({
        type:"checkbox",
        fieldLabel: "Check to open in New window",
         options:displayOptionsAnchorTargetSubdomainCarousel(),
        listeners: {
            selectionchanged: {
                scope:this,
                fn: this.updateHidden
            }
        },
        optionsProvider: this.optionsProvider,
        stateful: true,
        stateid: "mycheckbox",
        stateevent: ["selectionchange"],
        getState: function() { return this.getValue(); },
        applyState: function(state) { this.setValue(state) }
    });
```

And add the checkbox to `getRawValue` and `setValue` as well.

**References**

- [Class CQ.Form.Selection](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/?class=CQ.form.Selection)
- [Class Ext.state.Stateful](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.state.Stateful)
- [Class Ext.state.Provider](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.state.Provider)
- [ExtJS – Creating and using a State Provider](http://ahlearns.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/extjs-creating-and-using-a-state-provider/)